# MC33153 faults when applying high input

Tags: mosfet-driver

I'm exploring an Onsemi MC33153 IGBT/MOSFET driver and stuck with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVomjO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When turning SW1 on (closed), Fault pin turns low, Drive stays low (0.4V). Turning SW1 off (open), Fault pin turns high, Drive raises a tiny bit (to 0.42V), which is not as expected. Drain voltage keeps around 15V, which means to me that M1 is slightly open.

This is a simplified version of the "basic" implementation from the datasheet:
[image]

I've added R1 to simulate the load and apply some Drain-Source voltage. Measuring the Drive pin in open state (without a MOSFET connected) <s>yields the same results</s> sometimes shows high level (after falling transition on Input), but the behavior is unstable.

Raising input voltage to Vcc (16V) does not change anything, the signal voltage of 3.3V is sufficient for transition (datasheet mentions 2.7V as a threshold).

I've also tried multiple switchings of SW1 back and forth, the behavior did not change.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Nailed it! Thanks to *Tony Stewart* and *analogsystemsrf* I confirm that adding a 1000uF capacitor between Pin6 and FET Source (I suppose this is what's been meant by "decoupling") leads to reliable operation. Removing it raises the Fault signal and disables the Drive right away, so this is pretty much verified.

I've put together the whole circuit (STM32F1 controller, 3 MC33153's and 3 FETs connected) and it works.

*For those having the same problem*: the placement of a "minus" pin of the cap might be crucial! If this solution doesn't work for you, try moving the pin closer to the FET's Source, it should be between the Source and all other connections to the Ground.

Comment: The "base" application circuit shows a pull-up on pin4-input. Did you try it? Internals look like having few flip=flops, so a full transition on the input might be required. Also, main schematics shows the Input as active LOW.

Comment: It looks to me as a pull-up from Vee to GND. In my configuration Vee=GND (this is allowed by datasheet), so I have nothing to pull up to. But tried shorting Pin4 to GND, nothing changed.

Comment: Figure 35 shows the configuration exactly as yours. Follow it.

Comment: To achieve reliable operation, place 0.1uF within 1mm of the package. Use GND plane, with no slits under the IC. Goal? Minimize the inductance, so the onchip R_well_substrate will adequately dampen any ringing, to prevent overshoot of VDD pin. Ideal R is sqrt(L / C).

Comment: The cap itself (I've had only 0.62uF) didn't help, but I've disconnected the MOSFET and got the drive signal! Sometimes it appears, sometimes not, so I suppose you're right and there's a ringing somewhere. Will post an update when I find all the bugs, thanks to you and Tony Stewart I know where to look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fault is edge sensitive going high by 3 input AND.

Verify both pin 1 or 8 0V. **Either one with a loose connection to 0V may cause a fault with input floating.**

Be careful with layout and decouple supply close to IC.

use pullup R on input <10k

Answer (score 2):

The basic application for [**MC33153**](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC33153-D.PDF) indicates that to turn the output ON, the Input should be shorted to Vee, 
[image]

So, instead of applying +3.3V or leaving the Input floating, you should have a pull-up to Vcc, and use an open collector circuit to provide LOW to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried with 2K pull up, no juice. The input was not floating at any moment during operation, but didn't work. Also, I'm almost sure this exact circuit will work, but as my interest is mostly academic, I'd like to understand, why doesn't my circuit work.

Comment: Are you prototyping this for real, or just run some SPICE simulations? The schematics you presented does imply that the input is indeed floating when SW1 is open, contrary  to what you said. Electrical Engineering requires some attention to details.

Comment: For real, on an MB-102 breadboard, as I didn't have a SPICE model for MC33153. The first prototype had a floating Input and after your comment I've added the pull-up (always connected) and rewired SW1 to short the Input to Vee when closed, as you wrote in your answer. Sorry if my wording were confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the discussion as I was after some info.
I believe the MC33153 wiring you have here is wrong.
Pin 1 should not be tied to GND. Instead you have to connect it to VCC.
Otherwise there is nothing wrong with the IC driver. It is rock steady even with bigger MOSFET/IGBT bricks.

In the datasheet there is a line that states:

"Note that for proper  operation  of  the  Desaturation  Comparator  and  theFault Output, the Current Sense Input must be biased abovethe Overcurrent and Short Circuit Comparator thresholds.This can be accomplished by connecting Pin 1 to VCC."

I used the MC33153 for years on some 4kV/50A PS and no probs so far.

Good luck!

Comment: I believe your answer is not correct. Tieing pin 1 to ground disables the current sense. Tieing it to Vcc triggers both the overcurrent comparator and short circuit comparator in the MC33153!

Comment: It is also the opposite of the basic Application Fig 35 the datasheet provided (also shown in one of the answer above.)